# Diacritics in file names on macOS behave strangely

Tags: macos, filesystems

Consider the following, run on the terminal on macOS:

```
> touch ä
> ls
ä
> ls *
ä
> ls * | hexdump
00000000  c3 a4 0a
00000003
> ls | hexdump
00000000  61 cc 88 0a
00000004
```

Expanding `*` on the command line results in the file name being expanded normally, with its normal UTF-8 character values. However, when `ls` retrieves the file names in the current directory without them being given to it as parameter, for an unfathomable reason the `ä` character has now been transmogrified into an `a` with an UTF-8 combining diacritic. Does anybody have any idea why that's happening?

This is a bit problematic because programs that resolve file names in directories are seeing that exact same difference.

Answer (score 2):

macOS applies [Unicode normalization](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence#Normal_forms) to filenames; it's done so that programs would always find the exact same file regardless of whether they're using the composed or decomposed form.

Unusually, macOS with the HFS+ filesystem uses NFD normalization, which always *decomposes* the characters into base + combining diacritics.

(In the new APFS, the opposite NFC format is used for better compatibility, as non-macOS systems more commonly used the precomposed characters.)